# IsUserInRole not working in CSHTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code, but I don't know why this is not working properly.  I have a custom role provider created.

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Manager"))
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Management", "Index", "User")</li>
}
```

This is the custom code, the rest wasn't modified.

```
   public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {      
        UserRoleType usrt = (from usr in db.Users
                   join usrRole in db.UserRoles on usr.UserID equals usrRole.UserID
                   where usr.Email == username
                   select usrRole.UserRoleType).FirstOrDefault();

        if (roleName.Split(',').Contains(usrt.UserRoleTypeName))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

This does work when I do this:

```
UserRoleProvider roleProvider = System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider as UserRoleProvider;

if (roleProvider.IsUserInRole(httpContext.User.Identity.Name, Roles) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles))
            return true;
```

EDIT:

```
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string roleName)
    {
        return db.UserRoleTypes.Select(u => u.UserRoleTypeName).ToArray();

    }
```

Comment: `where usr.Email == username` is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this code does work.  I just don't why this doesn't work when I do @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Manager"))

Comment: Did you add the custom role provider to your web.config?

Comment: Yes <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UserRoleProvider">

Comment: did you do a `<clear />` in your providers section?

Comment: Yes, I do clear.  I updated, I don't know why its going to GetRolesForUser when I run it via HTML.  Is this correct?

Comment: The `IPrincipal` interface already declares a method `bool IsInRole(string role)`. Why not just shorten your code to `@if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out GetRolesForUser was written in correctly and it was pulling all the Users so it authenticated based on ALL users, which means it was in the first place.

Re-read the documentation to get my answer here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getrolesforuser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It appears that

```
User.IsInRole(rolename)
```

uses

```
MembershipProvider.GetRolesForUser(username)
```

It took me a while to figure that out.